# Issues after upgrading the servers PHP version

Tags: web-server, php.ini

I have created my project in Symfony 1.4.8 with Propel ORM. previously server had PHP version 5.2.* and i have upgraded it to 5.3.4, then the problem started giving some error in Propel.
the errors were,

> ```
> PHP Deprecated: Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
> ```

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /usr/local/lib/php/symfony/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/util/PropelPDO.php on line 42

PHP Warning: Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning: Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning: Module 'SQLite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Is there any config error that has to be taken care of?? please help!

Answer (score 1):

Magic quotes are deprecated as of Php 5.3

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

For the PDO. Check you php.ini if you have uncommented "extension=php_pdo.so" and your classe PDO to your database.

Comment: ok @sameer i will try that!